# Función Concatenar en Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la columna concatenar uso la siguiente función: =CONCATENAR(B2,",",B3)
esto debido a que tengo que obtener todos los productos que tiene la columna No cliente, el no cliente 500 tiene los productos 1 y 2 los cuales se muestran de manera correcta.

La duda es como puedo crear una formula la cual me identifique el cliente el numero de productos y el total de celdas a concatenar ?

ejemplo el cliente 520 tiene los productos 2,3,4 y 5 yo se como es la formula, pero asi tengo cliente con hasta 1000 productos, como se podria automatizar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con VBA sería muy fácil, pero sin VBA se me ocurre con una tabla dinámica. Te quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes en las filas el número del no cliente, y luego pones el producto en columnas y la cuenta de producto en valores. Si te sirve así genial, si no deberías pensar en código.

Edito:

Otra opción sería usar esta fórmula:

```
=SI(A3=A2;CONCATENAR(B3;",";C2);B3)
```

Esto suponiendo que tus datos comienzan en la fila 2, y al primero lo dejas con el valor del producto puesto manualmente. Quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De este modo la última fila del no cliente tendría todos los datos, siempre y cuando estuvieran ordenados... en caso de que no lo estén... la tabla dinámica sería mejor opción.